# Issue when implementing iRate

Tags: ios, xcode

When adding iRate to my app I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_iRate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like when you added the .m file to your project, it wasn't assigned to your target. Select iRate.m in the project navigator. Then bring up the utilities view on the right side of Xcode. Under Target Membership, make sure your app's target is checked. Try the build again.